# Cauchy Riemann equations and analyticity of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

**A**

At which points if any does the function

$$f(z) = z\operatorname{Re}(z) + \bar{z}\operatorname{Im}(z)$$
satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

**B**

At which points, if any is this function analytic. Justify your answer.

**Answer**

A. I applied the Cauchy Riemann equations and found that they are satisfied at x = 1, y = -1.

B. As they are not differentiable anywhere else in C, particularly in some neighbourhood of (1, -1), they function is analytic nowhere.

Are my answers for A and B correct?

Comment: Dear Jim, A. is false. And as to B., I don't see what you mean with "they are not differentiable" .

Comment: Carelessness during differentiation cost me again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Only at  0
B. Analytic Nowhere

Answer (score 0):

cauchy-riemann equation is satisfied at all the points which lie on the line x+y=0.

Comment: Incorrect. Write the function as $z^2/2+(1+i)z\bar z/2-(\bar z)^2$ and you will see that the $\bar z$-derivative is $(1+i)z/2-2\bar z$. This can't be zero unless $z=0$, because at all other points the two terms are of different absolute values.